# Максимальные значения осей в GraphView. Android

Tags: java, android, graphics

Имеется следующий код:

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(arr);
                graphView.addSeries(series);
                graphView.getViewport().setMaxX(31);
                graphView.getViewport().setMaxY(150);
                graphView.getViewport().setMinX(1);
                graphView.getViewport().setMinY(0);
```

И вроде как он должен создавать оси Х с минимальным значением 1, а максимальным 31, и Y, с минимальным 0 и максимальным 150

Однако на деле, почему-то, происходит следующее

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, в чем ошибка. Не хватало этих строк:

```
graphView.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
            graphView.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
```